# Image Cropping issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiimage, crop

I want to crop UIImage with the following code:

```
 - (UIImage*)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
     CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
     // or use the UIImage wherever you like
     UIImage * img =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
     CGImageRelease(imageRef);
     return img;
 }
```

This code is working fine in the simulator but giving unusual result on device.

Comment: describe further the "unusual result on device" ...

Comment: Check the `scale` of the image, on a retina device, you might need to adjust the coordinates of your rectangle accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @henser But the answer below worked foe me.
Actually the cropped area Image got bigger than cropped.
Using words like Guys are not allowed?

Comment: It is allowed to use the word 'Guys'. It is just not necessary nor advised to compliment or add unnecessary content to a question. Posts should be direct, succinct and straight-forward and yet should communicate the problem at its full extent. This facilitates communication and understanding. An edit is not a reprehension, it's just a cleaning matter for posterity. Glad your issue got solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIImage category and try adding this.

@implementation UIImage (Crop)

```
- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)cropRect {

    cropRect = CGRectMake(cropRect.origin.x*self.scale, 
                      cropRect.origin.y*self.scale, 
                      cropRect.size.width*self.scale, 
                      cropRect.size.height*self.scale);       

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], cropRect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef 
                                          scale:self.scale 
                                    orientation:self.imageOrientation]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
    - (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)oldImage {
            CGSize imageSize = oldImage.size;
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake( imageSize.width,imageSize.height - 150),NO,0.);
            [oldImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake( 0, -80) blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy alpha:1.];
            UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            return croppedImage;
    }
```

Comment: you can set height,width,x and y.

Comment: why you have decresed the size by 150

Comment: because i take screen shot and i have tabbar in bottom.

Comment: i am sharing photo on facebook.

Comment: Olright thanks buddy But I guess there some problem with Scale